# ioredis Error: connect ETIMEDOUT - Can't get connection to local redis server

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

### Problem

On my node.js backend, I initialized a redis server:

```
const options = {
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST, // localhost
  port: process.env.REDIS_PORT, // 6379 Redis standard port
  db: 0,
  // reconnect after
  retryStrategy: times => Math.min(times * 50, 2000),
  tls: {}
};

export const redis = new Redis(options);
```

Unfortunately, I always get this error message:

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/pascal/vipfy/vipfy-backend/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis.js:298:31)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:449:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

I installed redis locally and use the redis-cli to ping the local server, no password is set. It always gives a positive answer, but I can't seem to be able to reach it via ioredis. Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your redis server is running. You just try without options params, so it will try to connect your localhost redis automatically by host as `localhost` and port as `6379`.

```
redis = new Redis();
```

If you don't have any specific advantage try following, I am using following one and works well.

Package : `"redis": "^2.8.0"`

Code :

```
var redis = require('redis');
var redis_conn = redis.createClient();

redis_conn.set("key", "val");
```

Comment: As written above, the server is running as I was successfully pinging it via the redis-cli. Also, I explicitly tried using localhost and port 6379. Should make this more clear in my original comment.

Tried your example, but unfortunately, it is the same error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Seems like my problem was that I did not do redis.createClient. When switching to this, it seems to work.

Comment: Okay @Gh05d. Happy to help.